# How to Change the background Image of a Layout when a button clicked

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener

How to change the background image of a layout, using one button.

I know how to set one image for background of layout, but how to switch between TWO or more image? I think i will must create a array of images

**MainActivity.java**

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
        LinearLayout view = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout1);
        view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image);
        }
        });
```

For example: 
the background in the calculator should switch when you click the "equal" button

i press the equal button

[image]

and the background changes from the picture of Fiona to Shrek
[image]

Comment: please, describe your question better, do you want to show an array of images? or a gallery?

Comment: i wanna show an array of images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show an `Array` of images as background, you need to create your `Array`, and an `index` to point to a `position` within your `Array`

```
private int[] images;  // declare your array in global scope
private int imagesIndex = 0;
```

Then you need to populate your `Array` with `Drawable Resources`. You can do it in `onCreate() method`(if using `Array` in `Activity).

```
int numOfImages = 4;
images = new int[numOfImages];
images[0] = R.drawable.ic_launcher_background;
images[1] = R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground;
images[2] = R.drawable.fiona;
images[3] = R.drawable.shrek;
```

Finally in `Click Listener` of your `Button` you simply need to select a resource from your `Array`.

```
 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {
     LinearLayout view = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout1);
     view.setBackgroundResource(images[imagesIndex]); 
     ++imagesIndex;  // update index, so that next time it points to next resource
     if (imagesIndex == images.length - 1)
         imagesIndex = 0; // if we have reached at last index of array, simply restart from beginning.
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

try out this to switch between two images

```
final Switch s = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switch1);
s.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v){
        if (s.isChecked()){
           view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image1);
        }else{
            view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image2);
        }
    }
});
```

If you want to learn more, [contact me](https://m.facebook.com/samiun.nafis.685).